# At sign (@) is not being entered when I use Selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, email-validation

I have been trying to practice Selenium and I can't test the registration feature because of the email validation, but every single time I run the test, it enters everything except the "@" sign, and obviously it's a required character.
This is the website, I've been testing -> http://a.testaddressbook.com/
(Sorry, if it's messed up, this is the first time I posted something here)

Expected result:
yolo@test.com (to be displayed on the email input field)

Actual result:
yolotest.com
[without "@"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbedP.jpg)

Step Definition file (the important part of it):
[StepDef.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6XY2.jpg)

And the page which is reference to the step definition files:
[SignUp.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWOVn.jpg)

EDIT: I started with Eclipse and then I changed to IntelliJ (hoping that it was only an IDE settings issue, but it was not - worth a try tho).
I also tried to add the unicode of the "@" sign, it still didn't type "@".

As asked, below you can find snippets of the code:
SignUp.java  (page)

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class SignUp {

    @FindBy(id = "user_email")
    private WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(id = "user_password")
    private WebElement userPass;


    public void credentials(WebDriver driver) {
        Actions cred = new Actions(driver);
        cred.click(userName).sendKeys("yolo@test.com").perform();
        cred.click(userPass).sendKeys("Batman").perform();
    }
}
```

StepDef.java (step definition file)

```
@Then("^I fill out fields with information$")
public void i_fill_out_fields_with_information() throws Throwable {
    SignUp filldetails = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignUp.class);
    filldetails.credentials(driver);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

EDIT (suggested code):

```
package com.qa.quickstart.Bookthing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestThing {


    ChromeDriver driver;
    String url="http://a.testaddressbook.com/sign_in";


    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Laptop\\eclipse-workspace\\chromedriver.exe");
         driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get(url);


         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
         driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();
         WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@value='Sign up']")));
         WebElement email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("user_email")));
         email.sendKeys("apple@test.com");
         WebElement pass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("user_password")));
         pass.sendKeys("banana");

         Thread.sleep(15000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code in text form instead of posting screenshots. It will improve readability and searchability of the question.

Comment: I suspect some issue with charset. What is the default charset being used?

Comment: yes, the default charset is being used, and I didn't touch anything. In fact, I've only installed these IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ) recently.

Comment: Just in case, I checked it, and it is the default charset (Cp1252)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I managed to solve the problem!

Before the solution, I:

- I used Linux VM and used the same code. I found that my code actually works. So, I began to think something on my computer doesn't allow the "@" to be written by Selenium.
- uninstalled/re-installed Google Chrome
- Changed the keyboard layout (English was the default, but it also had a Hungarian layout as an option, later on I decided to re-install it, the solution didn't do any changes on it tho, the default is still English)

but, apparently the solution was the **Key.Chord**!
An example:

```
email.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, "batman@msn.com"));
```

or

```
email.sendKeys(Keys.chord("robin@msn.com"));
```

It's not professional, but it still works. I also found out that after this solution my original code worked. So, I could just stick to this code below:

```
email.sendKeys("apple@test.com");
```

In short, if you are in a similar situation, then just try **Key.Chord**! (and then try out your original code)

Comment: I had the same issue. Hungarian keyboard checks out as well :). However, `Keys.chord()` (or rather, adding `Keys.Null` to the end of the string because that's what it seems to do but there's no `chord()` method in the .NET library) didn't help. I'll look further.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code it worked fine.

```
@Test(enabled=true)
public void loginTry() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://a.testaddressbook.com/sign_in");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("sign-in")));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign up")).click();
    WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@value='Sign up']")));
    WebElement email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("user_email")));
    email.sendKeys("yolo@test.com");
    WebElement pass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("user_password")));
    pass.sendKeys("somepassword");
    Thread.sleep(15000);

}
```

Comment: no, unfortunately, it did not work :/ 
still the same result (it does not type "@")
At this point, I start to think it isn't a code issue.

Comment: But when I tried it is typing @ in email code. Is it possible to share full end to end code, I can debug it once. Thanks. Because independent code is working. Just check once...

Comment: I edited my post. Essentially, I used the same code what you have. (I made small changes because the driver.get("link") showed me an error, apart from that it's pretty much the same), and thank you for trying.
(this SHOULD work, but for some reason it is not typing the @ sign)